# Python: Getting rid of garbage strings present in a date

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file, In each line of the file I have a date. the format for the date is given below.

```
Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM CST
```

I want to convert the date in python format.

For example:

```
2013-12-15 6:50:52
```

The problem I am facing is how can I remove the garbage string attached to the date i.e (CST)

I took the following approach to convert the date

```
date_capture=datetime.datetime.strptime('Dec 11, 2013 11:55:00 AM','%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

But I still am unable to remove the garbage string CST from the date.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) methods:

```
s = "Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM CST"

new_s = " ".join(s.split()[:-1])

print new_s
```

**Output:**

```
Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM
```

Then, you can convert the date:

```
date_capture = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_s, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

You can also do this directly:

```
date_capture = datetime.datetime.strptime(" ".join(s.split()[:-1]), '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.rsplit):

```
>>> 'Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM CST'.rsplit(None, 1)[0]
'Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM'
>>> time_str = 'Dec 15, 2013 6:50:52 PM CST'.rsplit(None, 1)[0]
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 15, 6, 50, 52)
```